# Is it possible to start/stop a service-activator at runtime?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a web application that interfaces with another application through a message queue.  So, my web application has a service-actibator that is bound to an inbound message driven channel adapter; currently it is is always listening for messages on the queue.

However, there may be times where it is desiarable to turn that listening off without bouncing the application itself. For example, if the queue gets a backlog of messages and for whatever reason the web application that is listening for these messages begins to have performance issues and we want to isolate the application from the queue to help identify if that is the source of the performance problem or not.

The bottom line is we are trying to proactivey look for ways to help our support staff when needing to diagnose potential inter-system issues...without having to necessarily bounce the servers for a configuration change.

Then if it is determined that the interface to the external system should be turned back on then we would want to be able to re-start the service activator.

Is anything like this possible? Or is there an approach that I'm not thinking of that would allow this type of runtime start/stop capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
All Endpoints in the Spring Integration implement `org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle`.
From other side SI has a component for this purpose - [Control Bus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#groovy-control-bus)
So, it very simple:

```
<channel id="controlBusChannel"/>    
<control-bus input-channel="controlBusChannel"/>

<service-activator input-channel="stopMyServiceActivatorChannel"
    output-channel="controlBusChannel" expression="'@myServiceActivator.stop()'"/>

<service-activator id="myServiceActivator" input-channel="myInputChannel"
    output-channel="myOutupChannel"/>
```